# Bad Request when using Socialite on Facebook

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I am using Socialite Package (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite) in my project.I have done following:

- Register Application on Facebook
- Get Client Secret and ID
- Installed Socialite Package using composer
- configure .env files
- configure callback url

But when after successful callback, my app shows following errors on this command

`Socialite::drive("facebook")->user()`

> error: Client error:
>   POST 
>     https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/oauth/access_token`resulted in a`400 Bad Request

Response:

```
{
  "error":{
    "message": "URL \u0644\u0648\u0688 \u0646\u06c1\u06cc\u06ba 
  \u06a9\u06cc\u0627 \u062c\u0627 \u0633\u06a9\u062a\ (truncated...)
A:\xampp\htdocs\PLAGX_FRONTEND\px-web\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the SSL of your callback url, the response seems to be not properly decoded by the receiver party. Turning SSL on your localhost or deployment server could help.